# Can I receive detailed tx data via command line using only a lightclient?

Tags: raw-transaction, utxo, command-line-options

I recently tried to sync the Bitcoin blockchain, but my laptop does not have enough space on it. I want to be able to analyze UTXOs and raw transaction data.

Will a lightclient allow me to do this?

Comment: To be clear, you want to be able to analyze any transaction without storing all of the blocks?

Comment: Yes. I am hoping to use all of the same command line commands to analyze the transactions.

Answer (score 1):

No. Lightweight wallets are designed specifically only for the wallet user. It only stores transactions and UTXOs relevant to the wallet. It will not store any historical data or data that does not pertain to the wallet, so it is useless for trying to retrieve any arbitrary transaction.

Comment: Is there anyway to call tx info (from any transaction) from a full node using command line?

Comment: If you are running your own full node using the Bitcoin Core software and you have enabled the transaction index, then you can use the `getrawtransaction` command to retrieve any transaction that is in the blockchain or in the mempool. Not that this requires over 200 GB of disk space and can take several hours to sync.